# Why doesn't System.Include work when the Set is provided by a property?

Tags: delphi, properties, include, set

Why doesn't System.Include work when the Set is provided by a property?

```
TMyItem = (miOne, miTwo, miThree); 

TMyItems = set of TMyItem; 

TSomeClass = class
  private 
    FItems: TMyItems;
  protected
    procedure SetItem(val : TSetItems);
    function GetState : TSetItems;
  public
    property Items : TMyItems read GetMyItems write SetMyItems;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  c: TSomeClass;
begin
  c:=TSomeClass.Create;
  c.Items:=c.Items + [miTwo];  //WORKS OK
  Include(c.Items,miTwo); //COMPILE ERROR
end;
```

I'm using Win32 BDS 2006. Is this a bug, a feature, or operator error?

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the first version is an assignment to a property, while the second is a property being passed to a **var** parameter.  The Delphi compiler considers it an error to pass a property, even a read/write one, to a **var** parameter.  I don't think that makes any sense, but that's the way it works.

Comment: I didn't notice the var declaration in the help: [Delphi] procedure Include(var S: Type; I: Integer); I agree...that doesn't make sense.

Comment: It does make sense. Property could have getter and setter functions and you can override them. So compiler cannot use simple ASM instruction.

Comment: @DiGi: In that case, the compiler can call the getter, retrieve to a local variable, call the function, take the returned value, and pass it to the setter.  There's no good reason not to.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler yes, that is c.Items:=c.Items + [miTwo] from original code. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Include

Comment: @Mason Wheeler, property is an expression, while `Include` wants variable reference. However, I do agree what described high-level *sugar* could be done (in FPC :)